# Sorting ADF table leads to null pointer exception when I later try to retrieve row data from table

Tags: oracle-adf

I am creating an Adf table like this:

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.TargetsAssign.collectionModel}"
                            var="row"
                            rows="#{bindings.TargetsAssign.rangeSize}"
                            fetchSize="#{bindings.TargetsAssign.rangeSize}"
                            rowBandingInterval="0"
                            selectionListener="#{bindings.TargetsAssign.collectionModel.makeCurrent}"
                            rowSelection="multiple" 
                            styleClass="AFStretchWidth" columnStretching="last"
                            binding="#{pageFlowScope.mappingBean.m_mappingtable}"
                            id="t3">
```

All the columns in this table are sortable.
For selecting multiple rows in this table, Bean file contains following code:

```
RowKeySet rks = m_mappingtable.getSelectedRowKeys();
    Iterator itr = rks.iterator();
    DCBindingContainer bindings =  (DCBindingContainer)BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry();
    DCIteratorBinding targetIter = bindings.findIteratorBinding("TargetsAssign");
    RowSetIterator tableIterator = targetIter.getRowSetIterator();
    while (itr.hasNext())
    {
        key = (Key) ((List)itr.next()).get(0);
        Row row = tableIterator.getRow(key);
        String str=(String)row.getAttribute("TargetName");   /*----------------->> THis line is throwing Null pointer exception. 
         .
         .
         .further code......*/
    }
```

Before sorting table using sort option in UI everything works fine but once we sort the table and again try to select rows in table to perform some operation using above code, Null Pointer exception is thrown because Row `row = tableIterator.getRow(key)` returns null in this case.

Can anyone please tell why is it happening and how to fix it. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the full code of your jspx page

Comment: sorry, But I can't add full jspx code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Remove the selectionListener attribute of your table